# how to fix implicit boolean in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I changed the name of my xcode app product and I get this in build Settings under implicit boolean conversion: $(CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION)

What does that mean, Ive tried looking for details, is it something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain this has nothing to do with changing your project's "`PRODUCT_NAME`", but instead its a checkbox you might have accidentally set in your Project or Build Settings.

`CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION` being set to true means

> Warn about various implicit conversions that can lose information or
>   are otherwise suspicious.

[The most obvious example being an implicit conversion to a smaller or less-precise type, such as passing an NSUInteger (e.g., from an ANDed bit mask) where a BOOL is expected](https://github.com/boredzo/Warnings-xcconfig/wiki/Warnings-Explained).